# Java ArrayList get() method doesn't return Point object?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, get, point

so i created an ArrayList of Point objects but when i'm using the get() method of the ArrayList it seems that it does not return Point object.. why is this happening?

```
public class SkylineDC {
    public static void openAndReadFile(String path,ArrayList pointsList){
        //opening of the file
        Scanner inputFile=null;
        try{
            inputFile=new Scanner(new File(path));
        }
        catch (Exception e1){
            try{
                inputFile=new Scanner(new File(path+".txt"));
            }
            catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("File not found..");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        //reading of the file
        short listSize=inputFile.nextShort();
        pointsList=new ArrayList<Point>(listSize);
        //pointsList.add(new Point(10,10));
        //System.out.println("Size of List:"+pointsList.size());
        pointsList.get(0).
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path=args[0];
        ArrayList totalPoints=null;

        openAndReadFile(path,totalPoints);

        //System.out.println("finish");
    }

}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList pointsList`

you're using a raw type in the declaration.

Change it to `ArrayList<Point> pointsList`

Also:

`ArrayList totalPoints=null` should not be the raw type either.  Change to `ArrayList<Point> totalPoints = new ArrayList<>()`

I would furthermore suggest simply having your method *return* a `List<Point>` rather than trying to populate an existing list.  I don't even know if the code you currently have will run as expected.  My suspicion is that it will not.

Comment: thanks a lot! you 're right it doesn't work like that but since in Java arguments are passed by reference why it's not working?

Comment: because you were re-assigning the list variable within your method.